# Java: @AfterStep, @BeforeStep do not work in cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber

In my Java and maven project I have used cucumber for BDD test.
Here is the dependency I use:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

my `Hooks` class:

```
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.AfterStep;
import cucumber.api.java.BeforeStep;


public class Hooks  {

    @Before
    public void init() {
        System.out.println( " Before Scenario " );
    }

    @After
    public void cleanUp() {
        System.out.println( " After Scenario " );
    }


    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep() {
        System.out.println("======>  This is before step  <======");
        //Do something before executing the step
    }

    @AfterStep
    public void afterStep() {
        System.out.println("======>  This is after step  <======");

    }
}
```

But when I run my cucumber test it just prints `Before Scenario`, and `After Scenario`. ***Meanwhile***, I expect to see, `This is before step`, and `This is after step` 
***before***, and ***after*** each step.

So, why `@AfterStep`, and `@BeforeStep` do not work?

Comment: You could achieve it by overriding the methods public void testStarted(Description description){} and public void testFinished(Description description){} of class org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener (and  public void testFailure(Failure failure){} in case the step fails). You should implement a logic to get the step name.

Comment: Could you provide a small snippet which reproduce your issue? It works as expected for me.

Answer (score 4):

- you should provide a small example which others can use to reproduce your problem

Have a look at this small snippet which is working

Assume the following structure

```
pom.xml
src/test/java/TestRunner.java
src/test/java/stepdefs/StepDefinitions.java
src/test/java/stepdefs/Hooks.java
src/test/resource/features/demo.feature
```

**pom.xml**

```
...
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <version.cucumber>4.2.0</version.cucumber>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${version.cucumber}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
...
```

**TestRunner.java**

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resource/features"},
        glue = {"stepdefs"}
         )
public class TestRunner {
}
```

**StepDefinitions.java**

```
package stepdefs;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class StepDefinitions {
    @Given("^a successful step$")
    public void aSuccessfulStep() {
        System.out.println("    aSuccessfulStep()");
    }

    @When("doing something")
    public void doingSomething() {
        System.out.println("    doingSomething()");
    }

    @Then("something happen")
    public void somethingHappen() {
        System.out.println("    somethingHappen()");
    }
}
```

**Hooks.java**

```
package stepdefs;

import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.AfterStep;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.BeforeStep;

public class Hooks {
    @Before
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("@Before scenario");
    }

    @After
    public void cleanUp() {
        System.out.println("@After scenario");
    }

    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep() {
        System.out.println("  @BeforeStep");
    }

    @AfterStep
    public void afterStep() {
        System.out.println("  @AfterStep");
    }
}
```

**demo.feature**

```
Feature: Test cucumber reporting plugin

  Scenario: Run a non failing scenario
    Given a successful step
    When doing something
    Then something happen
```

running the tests

```
$ mvn clean test
```

produces following output

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestRunner
@Before scenario
  @BeforeStep
    aSuccessfulStep()
  @AfterStep
  @BeforeStep
    doingSomething()
  @AfterStep
  @BeforeStep
    somethingHappen()
  @AfterStep
@After scenario

1 Scenarios (1 passed)
3 Steps (3 passed)
```

Comment: Could you please answer this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59453283/is-it-possible-to-use-afterstep-meanwhile-using-cucumber-extentsreport